# Is await require in sleep function

Tags: typescript, asynchronous, async-await

Interesting that without await function the typescript is not complaint and the function is work.

First,
Wondering that, do we really need `async await` in our function?

And,
I wanna to avoid the boilerplate of return `:Promise<void>` for every fn which with `async`, any clue we can void that?

```
const App = () => {
  const [ isOpen, setIsOpen ] = useState(false);


  const sleep = (ms: number): Promise<void> => {
     return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
  }

 // not delay and print "didn't stop", "end", but setIsOpen fn will be delay 2 second
 const withoutAsyncAwait = () => {
   console.log("didn't stop");
   sleep(2000);
   setIsOpen(true); // ---> this will be trigger after 2000
   console.log("end")
 }

 // print "stop await 2second", and stop 2 second 
 const withAsyncAwait = async (): Promise<void> => {
   console.log("stop await 2second");
   await sleep(2000)
   setIsOpen(true);
   console.log("start await");
 }

 return (
  <>
    <div onClick={withAsyncAwait}>
     A Test Button with Await
    </div>
    <div onClick={withoutAsyncAwait}>
      A Test Button without Async await
    </div>
  </>
 )

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> First, Wondering that, do we really need `async await` in our function?

If you mean, do you need `await` on `sleep(2000)` to suspend function execution for two seconds before continuing, then yes, you do. Your *"this will trigger after 2000"* comment in `withoutAsyncAwait` is incorrect. It will "trigger" immediately after the call to `sleep`, with no delay.

> And, I wanna to avoid the boilerplate of return `:Promise<void>` for every fn which with `async`, any clue we can void that?

In the case of `withAsyncAwait`, literally just leave it off, and TypeScript will infer that from the fact it's `async` and what you're returning from the function (in that example, nothing, so `void`). For `sleep`, you could just leave it off as well, and TypeScript would infer the return value of `Promise<unknown>`, which is good enough.

Answer (score -2):

Async await, is used to let the compiler know to wait for the "xyz" thing to load, before continuing the next line of code.

Attempting to load anything (for example, fetching some data from a server) without using Async await, will lead us to this `Promise { <pending> }` instead of the data you requested.